# Element.update rjs error while using link_to_remote in rails

Tags: rjs, link-to-remote

I am using rails 2.3.2

I have  a link_to_remote functions

```
           <%= link_to_remote "Comments ", {
 :url => {:controller => "blogs",:action => "fetchcomments",:id => blog.id}} %> |
```

and the rails action as

```
        def fetchcomments
           unless params[:id].nil?
           @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])

           respond_to do |format|
             format.js do
              render :update do |page|
                  page.replace_html("comm", 'hi')
               end
             end
          end
        end
```

The above code throws me the error as

```
    try {
     Element.update("comm", "hi");
       } catch (e) { alert('RJS error:\n\n' + e.toString());                    
       alert('Element.update(\"comm\", \"hi\");'); throw e }
```

Please give me suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Remove `unless params[:id].nil?` and it will work if you have an element with the id 'comm' on the page that makes the request. Of course it will replace whatever is inside with the word 'hi'.